# Alter SaveChanges when Seeding database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, autofac

I have a setup where I use a service to log a user in and autofill the CreatedBy, UpdatedBy, ... fields for my entities. Because of this my SaveChanges method looks like this:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var modifiedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(x => x.Entity is IAuditableEntity
                        && (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified));

    var activeUserId = ActiveUserService.UserId;
    var username = Users.First(x => x.Id == activeUserId).UserName;

    foreach (var entry in modifiedEntries)
    {
        IAuditableEntity entity = entry.Entity as IAuditableEntity;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
        {
            throw new AuthenticationException(
                "Trying to save entities of type IAuditable while not logged in. Use the IActiveUserService to set a logged in user");
        }

        if (entity != null)
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                entity.CreatedBy = username;
                entity.CreatedAt = now;
            }
            else
            {
                base.Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedBy).IsModified = false;
                base.Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedAt).IsModified = false;
            }

            entity.UpdatedBy = username;
            entity.UpdatedAt = now;
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

The problem is when I'm seeding my database, Autofac isn't running and isn't injecting my services. Is it possible somewhere set a flag of some sort that when I'm seeding my database I use a default username or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, if there is no user logged in (so no `activeUserId`) it will break with an exception on `First()`:

```
var username = Users.First(x => x.Id == activeUserId).UserName;
```

And so the line:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
```

will never be true.

I would take a nullable variable into the method: `SaveChanges(int? activeUserId = null)`, and when called by your Seed-method it will be null, and you can handle that to set the username into SYSTEM. But for all your other code you can supply the id of the user, and handle that.

Edit: to summary: the method itself should not check if the user is logged in, do that someplace else.

Comment: Adding a parameter to the savechanges is a good idea! I think I'm going to use that.

Answer (score 0):

My current work-around is creating an other SaveChanges-method when seeding the database which sets a default user.

```
internal int SaveChangesWithDefaultUser()
{
    var modifiedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(x => x.Entity is IAuditableEntity
                    && (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified));

    var username = "SYSTEM";

    foreach (var entry in modifiedEntries)
    {
        IAuditableEntity entity = entry.Entity as IAuditableEntity;

        if (entity != null)
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                entity.CreatedBy = username;
                entity.CreatedAt = now;
            }
            else
            {
                base.Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedBy).IsModified = false;
                base.Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedAt).IsModified = false;
            }

            entity.UpdatedBy = username;
            entity.UpdatedAt = now;
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```